# How do I send email through HTML and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, email, send

I have a contact form on my website and I wanted to make a send button. I would not want an e-mail program on the computer to start, I just want the text to be sent to my e-mail right away by just pressing the button. I have searched for weeks now on the internet and I am giving up.

```
<form method="post" name="contact" action="#">
    <label for="author">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="author" name="author" class="required input_field" />
    <div class="cleaner h10"></div>

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" class="validate-email required input_field" name="email" id="email" />
    <div class="cleaner h10"></div>

    <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
    <input type="text" class="validate-subject required input_field" name="subject" id="subject"/>                             
    <div class="cleaner h10"></div>

    <label for="text">Message:</label>
    <textarea id="text" name="text" rows="0" cols="0" class="required"></textarea>
    <div class="cleaner h10"></div>             

    <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" name="submit" class="submit_btn float_l" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset" name="reset" class="submit_btn float_r" />
</form>
```

Comment: You can't. You need a backend scripting language like PHP to handle the request on the server and initiate the sending of the email. JS cannot do this. Also, I can't believe you've tried for weeks searching the internet, this is day 1 of web development. Just Google "PHP email script tutorial".

Comment: Client side code cannot do this. You would need to use a backend language to do something like this. i.e. PHP, ASP.NET etc

Comment: Well obviously the fact that I have searched for weeks becomes a lot more clear now when you say it can't be done with JS, because I was looking for the answer to be in JS. Thank you for your answer, however, stating that I am lying was not so helpful. Yes, it might be day 1 of web development, but I am no web designer!

Comment: Is it to much php code for you guys to show me an example?

Comment: I imagine it can be done with js, if you use node.js

Comment: `Is it to much php code for you guys to show me an example?` - A very simple `php email tutorial` google search will spawn innumerable examples for you

Comment: Yah I have a idea you can do same with third party api also

Comment: @NimChimpsky it still is server side

Comment: Here is your php code: `mail('my@email.com', $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message']); echo 'mail sent, bye';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of sending a mail happens server-side, HTML/JavaScript is client-side. As far as I can see you're not using a web-server nor are you hosting the website somewhere.

There is a FakeSendMail option with the new install from [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/ro/index.html) which you could use to emulate the mail() function from PHP. XAMPP is one of the most known localhost web servers , which you could use to finish your project, in case you don't really need that mail to be actually sent. If you do, I recommend using a webhosting.

But first you need to understand the difference between Client-Side and Server-Side. As far as Client Side is concerned, all it does is render your static data. (HTML/CSS/JS). But, as for Server Side, there is a lot more use to it, as you can work with a database, fetch and insert data from or to it, and eventually render data which will be processed by the Browser (client side)

Answer (score 6):

Maybe if you don't want to use **php**, you may try just use an **external API** to provide you the email to be sent.

**Mandrill** can do that.
*It's free up to 12k emails per month.*

In you page the code would be like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: “POST”,
  url: “https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json”,
  data: {
    ‘key’: ‘YOUR API KEY HERE’,
    ‘message’: {
      ‘from_email’: ‘YOUR@EMAIL.HERE’,
      ‘to’: [
          {
            ‘email’: ‘RECIPIENT_NO_1@EMAIL.HERE’,
            ‘name’: ‘RECIPIENT NAME (OPTIONAL)’,
            ‘type’: ‘to’
          },
          {
            ‘email’: ‘RECIPIENT_NO_2@EMAIL.HERE’,
            ‘name’: ‘ANOTHER RECIPIENT NAME (OPTIONAL)’,
            ‘type’: ‘to’
          }
        ],
      ‘autotext’: ‘true’,
      ‘subject’: ‘YOUR SUBJECT HERE!’,
      ‘html’: ‘YOUR EMAIL CONTENT HERE! YOU CAN USE HTML!’
    }
  }
 }).done(function(response) {
   console.log(response); // if you're into that sorta thing
 });
```

Here how:

https://medium.com/design-startups/b53319616782

http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/mandrill
(CodeCademy can teach how to use the API)

Answer (score 1):

This maybe what are you searching for: http://www.sanwebe.com/2011/12/making-simple-jquery-ajax-contact-form . You can only do what do you want by using PHP and HTML + AJAX. Create the form in HTML and than send the request + data using Jquery POST request like this:

```
        $.post('sendmail.php', post_data, function(response){  ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you 'searched' the net for weeks either :)
After one google search I got the following:
https://medium.com/design-startups/b53319616782

Thechnically it is not possible to send emails with javascript alone. You always need a backend service. But as described in the link above, there are mostly free (depends on volume) services available (as mentioned in the article above: https://mandrill.com/).

here is the code example of the link above:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json',
  data: {
    'key’: 'YOUR API KEY HERE’,
    'message': {
      'from_email': 'YOUR@EMAIL.HERE',
      'to': [
          {
            'email': 'RECIPIENT_NO_1@EMAIL.HERE',
            'name': 'RECIPIENT NAME (OPTIONAL)',
            'type': 'to'
          },
          {
            'email': 'RECIPIENT_NO_2@EMAIL.HERE',
            'name': 'ANOTHER RECIPIENT NAME (OPTIONAL)',
            'type': 'to'
          }
        ],
      'autotext': 'true',
      'subject': 'YOUR SUBJECT HERE!',
      'html': 'YOUR EMAIL CONTENT HERE! YOU CAN USE HTML!'
    }
  }
}).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response); // if you're into that sorta thing
});
```

Hope this helps.

Best regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I am being lazy and copied shamelessly from W3Schools (Please don't go and say how crappy W3schools is, I know but this serves the purpose!)>

```
<h2>Feedback Form</h2>
<?php
// display form if user has not clicked submit
if (!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  ?>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
  From: <input type="text" name="from"><br>
  Subject: <input type="text" name="subject"><br>
  Message: <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Feedback">
  </form>
  <?php 
} else {    // the user has submitted the form
  // Check if the "from" input field is filled out
  if (isset($_POST["from"])) {
    $from = $_POST["from"]; // sender
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    // message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
    // send mail
    mail("webmaster@example.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
    echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";
  }
}
?>
```